# Vanilla JavaScript - trying to update array elements when multiple conditions have been met

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that accepts an array, and prints "yummy" each time one of the values is equal to "food".  The second requirement is to update (replace) the entire array if no array elements are "food", print out "I'm hungry" once.

The second condition is where I'm running into difficulty and unsure of how to proceed.

I'm including the two test cases, the second of which I'm attempting to trigger the second set of conditions with.

```
function alwaysHungry(array){
  // iterate through the array values using a for() loop
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    // for each element equal to "food", change to yummy
    if (array[i] === 'food'){
      array[i] = 'yummy';
    }
    // if no array elements are "food", print "I'm hungry" only once
     else if(array[i] !== 'food'){ // this is checking any array index, not simply the first
      array[i] = "I\'m hungry";
    }
    // return array;  // returning the array here will short circuit the for loop
  }
  return array;
}
// Test cases
console.log(alwaysHungry(['food','drink','soda','food','drink']));  
// Expected result => ["yummy", "drink", "soda", "yummy", "drink"]

console.log(alwaysHungry(['rocks','air','water']));  
// Expected result => ["I'm hungry"]
```

As a side note, the question above is a variation of a problem I'm encountering in a bootcamp program and I'm trying to understand/solve the problem without relying heavily on built-in methods.

What I really want to get out of this is understanding how to zero in on the 2nd test case when the value "food" is not present and update accordingly.  I understand already that my (else if) logic above will update any array element not equal to "food", instead of updating only the array (test case) where "food" is entirely not present.

Here is a [JSBin link](https://jsbin.com/harunab/edit?js,console) for reference and thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the challenge require you to return the array that was passed in? Or can you create a new array and return that instead?

Comment: I think creating an empty placeholder array, eg `var newArray = [];`, is perfectly acceptable.  I've done this a number of times before with similar array oriented challenges.  Then using `newArray.push(array[i])` to push in the array values.  In the end, I didn't end up moving forward with this option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a flag `hungry` and initialize this variable with `false`. Then check the values of the array and update if necessary and set the flag to `true`.

At the the end return depending of `hungry` either an array with `["I'm hungry"]` or the updated array.

```js
function alwaysHungry(array) {
    var hungry = true;
    // iterate through the array values using a for() loop
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // for each element equal to "food", change to yummy
        if (array[i] === 'food') {
            array[i] = 'yummy';
            hungry = false;
        }
    }
    return hungry
        ? ["I'm hungry"]
        : array;
}

// Test cases
console.log(alwaysHungry(['food','drink','soda','food','drink']));  
// Expected result => ["yummy", "drink", "soda", "yummy", "drink"]

console.log(alwaysHungry(['rocks','air','water']));  
// Expected result => ["I'm hungry"]
```

Comment: A classmate suggested a Boolean to me earlier and now I see a lot more clearly how that could have been applied.  Thank you Nina.